# bison++ command not found

Tags: compiling

I have a source code that was written in late 90s. One portion of the code requires bison++ (parser) to compile source files written in c++. Without bison++ I cannot proceed with compilation.

I did try to find bison++ package over the internet but did not succeed. Does anybody know where I can get bison++ package from ?
I am running RHEL 7.3 Linux and gcc-4.8. on 64 bit architecture.

Answer (score 1):

Development on `bison++` [seems to have ended in 1993](https://code.google.com/archive/p/flexpp-bisonpp/).

The source code [is still available](https://code.google.com/archive/p/flexpp-bisonpp/downloads) and there are [RPM packages for Mandriva Linux](https://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=bison%2B%2B).

Comment: Thank you very much for directing to me to the link. However, now I am experiencing a new problem in installing flex++. When trying to run  make file I get this error gen.o: In function `make_tables':
gen.c:(.text+0x1c31): undefined reference to `flexscan'. Any idea on what is going wrong ?

Comment: @RavindraGudishala Sorry, I haven't used these tools myself and I don't current have access ta a GCC 4.5 installation to test with.